Internal Speakers Not Working on Samsung Galaxy Book4 Pro 14" with Ubuntu, Headphone Jack Works
I recently installed Ubuntu on my Samsung Galaxy Book4 Pro 14" (Ultra7-155H), and while the headphone jack works perfectly, the internal speakers are not functioning at all. Here are the details of my setup and what I've tried so far:
System Specifications:

Model: Samsung Galaxy Book4 Pro 14" (Ultra7-155H)
Processor: Intel Core Ultra 7 (14th Gen)
Graphics: Intel Arc Graphics
Audio: Quad Speakers
Wi-Fi Standard: Wi-Fi 6E
Display: OLED WQXGA+
Ubuntu Version: [Add your Ubuntu version here]

What I Have Tried:
Updated the system and kernel:

bash

Copy code

sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade


Installed the sof-firmware package:

bash
Copy code
sudo apt install sof-firmware

Modified ALSA configuration by adding the following to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf:

Copy code
options snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=1

Loaded the snd_hda_intel module:

bash
Copy code
sudo modprobe snd_hda_intel

Rebooted the system and verified audio output, but the speakers still do not work.
Observations:

Headphones work fine through the 3.5mm jack.
The internal speakers are completely silent.

Questions:

Is there any additional configuration or workaround I can try to get the internal speakers to work?
Could this be a driver issue with Ubuntu not fully supporting the Galaxy Book4 Pro's hardware?
Are there any patches or third-party solutions I can explore to address this problem?

I’ve also referred to the Arch Linux Wiki for Samsung laptops but didn’t find a solution that resolved my issue. Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks for your help. I try both Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and Ubuntu 24.10
Both had same problem that headphones jacket works fine but internal speakers not working.
My laptop sound card is Realtek ALC208.
The complete laptop specifications can be find here.
https://www.elgiganten.se/product/datorer-kontor/datorer/laptop/samsung-galaxy-book4-pro-14-barbar-dator-u7-155h16512/739986#
I greatly appreciate your help.

We don't know what Ubuntu product/release you're using, so we're limited in what we can provide. Drivers are kernel modules; so release details are the starting point, and if using a LTS release (which has kernel stack options) there are more options available; but you've given few details in a hard to read post.  Are you using an older release; given you tagged ALSA & PulseAudio, where Pipewire is default for newer versions etc - we won't know unless told

Thanks for your help. I try both Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and Ubuntu 24.1
Both had same problem that headphones jacket works fine but internal speakers not working. My laptop sound card is Realtek ALC208. The complete laptop specifications can be find here. https://www.elgiganten.se/product/datorer-kontor/datorer/laptop/samsung-galaxy-book4-pro-14-barbar-dator-u7-155h16512/739986#
I greatly appreciate your help.

Please let me know if you want me to provide more information.

Ubuntu releases are year.month in format; so 24.1 would specify Ubuntu release from 2024-January where there was no such release. This is a Q&A or Question & Answer site; with comments from readers to the OP or Original Poster, answers should be via edits to the question, where comments will get removed.  You've now marked this question as self-answered though (written your own answer)
